# Google Universal cross domain upgrade

Tags: google-analytics

This is my first post and I hope someone can help. We have multimpule websites which get tracked under one profile in the classic version of Google Analytics. All sites currently have the classic code for tracking.  The profile has been upgraded and I was about to change the coding over to the universal code on one of the 10 websites with some configuration. The question I can't see the answer to is. Do I have to change all the 10 websites over to the universal code at the same time?

Can I run 9 sites with the classic code and one with universal if they are all getting pulled into the same profile?

For example I have siteA.com, SiteB.com, Site_X.com etc. I really only want to change SiteB.com at this time.

Comment: I would ask this in the Google+ community. this question really doesn't belong here https://plus.google.com/u/0/communities/114481059214254340537  or http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

For cross domain tracking data is appended to the url to transfer it to the other domain (as cookie data is domain specific).

Universal Analytics appends only the client id (as "_ga" query parameter) whereas the older version of the tracking code expects all information from the utm cookies in the Url. So you should not expect cross domain traffic to be tracked properly between domains that use different versions of the GA tracking code (instead you will get a new session for a different user).